# How do I include a pound sign and a comma to a regex expression search?

Tags: regex

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I need to search websites for various number ranges. For example, 250-7,000. The numbers I'm searching for on a page always begin with a `#` sign. So `#366` or `#5,432`. I came up with this regular expression to search for the basic number range:

```
^(3[5-8][0-9]|39[0-9]|[4-9][0-9]{2}|[1-6][0-9]{3}|7000)$
```

However, that doesn't account for the # sign at the beginning or the comma if the number is 1,000 or greater. I'm not sure how to include those two factors. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this regex:

```
^#(2[5-9][0-9]|[3-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-6],[0-9][0-9][0-9]|7,000)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
2[5-9][0-9]            match 250-299
[3-9][0-9][0-9]        or match 300-999
[1-6],[0-9][0-9][0-9]  or match 1,000 - 6,999
7,000                  or match 7,000
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: Straight and simple.